# How to embed scikitplot in PyQt?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

There is a package called `scikitplot` that has a few tools that are very useful for my application. It has the possibility to plot some specific graphs automatically, by just calling a single function. The problem is that I need to embed these plots inside a PyQt window. I know that when working with `matplotlib` [it is possible to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36086361/embed-matplotlib-in-pyqt-with-multiple-plot) by using the PyQt backend. However, in this case I don't really know how to proceed due to the fact that the `scikitplot` functions return a plot each, and I don't know how to add an existing plot to a figure widget.

The code should be something like this (it obviosuly doesn't work but I hope it helps explaining my problem):

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import scikitplot as skplt
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

class ExampleWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):        
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._main = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._main)

        ## Lines to make minimal example
        X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33)
        nb = GaussianNB()
        nb.fit(X_train, y_train)
        predicted_probas = nb.predict_proba(X_test)

        ## The plots I want to show in the window
        ## It doesn't work because they aren't widgets, but I hope you get the idea
        plot1 = skplt.metrics.plot_cumulative_gain(y_test, predicted_probas)
        plot2 = skplt.metrics.plot_roc(y_test, predicted_probas)

        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(plot1)
        layout.addWidget(plot2)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.showMaximized()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    ex = ExampleWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create the axes inside your application and pass it to the plotting function.

```
    self.figure1 = matplotlib.figure.Figure()
    self.canvas1 = FigureCanvas(self.figure1)
    self.toolbar1 = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas1, self)
    self.ax1 = self.figure1.add_subplot(111)
    layout.addWidget(self.canvas1)
    layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)

    plot1 = skplt.metrics.plot_cumulative_gain(y_test, predicted_probas, ax=self.ax1)
```

Same for the second plot.

Note that this is written from the top of my head without testing since I do not have `scikitplot` available.